# DiffUtil not updating ListAdapter after updating ArrayList contents

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mvvm

I am trying to update ArrayList which is inside in MutableLiveData. 
whenever I change the content in ArrayList, ListAdapter is not updating.

**ViewModel**

```
private var _tileNumberList:MutableLiveData<ArrayList<TileNumber>> = MutableLiveData()

var tempTileNumberList: ArrayList<TileNumber> = ArrayList()

val tileNumberList:LiveData<ArrayList<TileNumber>>
get() = _tileNumberList

init {
    for (i in 1..9){
        for (j in 1..9){
            //tileNumberList.add(TileNumber(0,i,j))
            tempTileNumberList.add(TileNumber(0,i,j))
        }
    }

 fun onStart() {

        tempTileNumberList[count].number = 8
        _tileNumberList.value = tempTileNumberList
        count++

    }
```

whenever I call onStart method list values changes but ListAdapter not updating with latest values

**MainActivity**

```
backTrackingViewModel.tileNumberList.observe(this, Observer {
               it?.let {
                   //adapter.submitList(null)
                   adapter.submitList( it)
               }
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "Hey",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        })
```

when i set adapter.submitList(null) then my ListAdapter is updating

**TileNumber**

```
data class TileNumber(var number:Int,val row:Int,val column:Int) {
}
```

I tried this link references but didn't work

[ListAdapter not updating item in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726385/listadapter-not-updating-item-in-recyclerview)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50062174/6925888 (this is not a good solution)

[DiffUtil ItemCallback areContentsTheSame() always returns true after updating an item on the ListAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57876118/diffutil-itemcallback-arecontentsthesame-always-returns-true-after-updating-an)

Comment: Please add description of the property tileNumberList.

Comment: @mike check i updated question and code also.

Comment: According to the linked question "So if you pass the same list to the adapter it does not even call the DiffUtil". Did you check that?

Comment: So, do you have a Toast notification?

Comment: @sanjeev yes I pass the same list and i call DiffUtil.

Comment: @Mike yes mike I am getting toast every time when I press onStart.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should initialize tileNumberList list like this

```
var tileNumberList: LiveData<ArrayList<TileNumber>> =  _tileNumberList
```

And then observe it in MainActivity just like you're doing it

Comment: This doesn't make sense

Comment: Why not? changing value of `_tileNumberList` will trigger `tileNumberList` which we are observing in Fragment

Answer (score 0):

I have two possible options why this code doesn't work:

1. Items are changed in place - i.e. you change the items inside the list. Since the list is passed to adapter, the adapter's list is changed as well.
   Solution:

   _tileNumberList.value = tempTileNumberList.toList()
2. You haven't overridden **equals()** and **hashCode()** for TileNumber class.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, let the correct item position is not going to change but only content going to change. (on the same position of list), I tried this but no luck.

Comment: You should also try setting item directly:
 tempTileNumberList[count] = TileNumber(number = 8)

Answer (score 0):

According to `ListAdapter.SubmitList()` documentation, until you pass the list with the same reference you will never update your list. To make it work you can simply invoke:

```
adapter.submitList(it.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
 fun onStart() {

        tempTileNumberList[count].number = 8
        _tileNumberList.value = tempTileNumberList
        count++

    }
```

with this:

```
 fun onStart() {

        val tileNumber = tempTileNumberList[count].copy()  
        tileNumber.number = 8 
        tempTileNumberList.set(count, tileNumber)  
        _tileNumberList.value = tempTileNumberList
        count++

    }
```

Here I am using Kotlin data class **copy()** method.